# UIScrollView centered on launch

Tags: ios, swift, view, uiscrollview, scrollview

I added a `UIScrollView` to my `ViewController` so I can implement a pull-to-refresh function but I have a problem. When the `view controller` loads, the `scroll view` moves the `view` under the iPhone top bar, which destroys my design's centering.

Below is not the actual design but this is an illustration of what's happening. Is there a way to have the `scroll view` load as a normal `view` and preserve my design?

[image: View]

[image: Scroll View]

Comment: paste the constraints of it

Answer (score 0):

Alright, found it!

```
scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```